# How to prove these definitions of an analytic set are equivalent?

Tags: metric-spaces, definition, descriptive-set-theory, polish-spaces

Let $F$ be a set and $\mathcal F$ a collection of subsets of $F$ such that $\emptyset \in \mathcal F$. We denote by $F_\sigma$ (resp. $F_\delta$) the closure of $F$ under countable union (resp. intersection). Let $F_{\sigma \delta} := (F_\sigma)_\delta$. If $E$ is a topological space, then $\mathcal K (E)$ denotes the collection of all compact subsets of $E$.

Let $F$ be a metric space together with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$. A subset $A$ of $F$ is called **$\mathcal F$-analytic** if

- [Def 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set) there exists a Polish space $E$ and a continuous map $f:E \to F$ such that $A = f(E)$.
- [Def 2](https://almostsuremath.com/2018/12/24/analytic-sets/) there exists a compact metric space $E$ and $B \in (\mathcal K (E) \times \mathcal F)_{\sigma \delta}$, such that $A$ is the projection of $B$ onto $F$.

**Def 2** is taken from page 41 of Dellacherie/Meyer's *Probabilities and Potential*.
[image]

It is mentioned [here](https://planetmath.org/analyticset1) that they are equivalent, but there is no proof. Could you elaborate on how to prove this equivalence?

Comment: First of all, the equivalence of these definitions is only when the paved space $(F, \mathcal{F})$ is a Polish space $F$ and its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. In particular, $F$ cannot merely be a metric space with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Does that make the problem tractable to you?